# Tablesorter: filtering by multiple, but not all, columns

Tags: tablesorter

I'm using [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs) with an external filter. (ctrl-F 'filter_external') on the linked page. From the docs:

> These external inputs have one requirement, they must have a
>   data-column="#", where the # targets the column (zero-based index),
>   pointing to a specific column to search.
>
> ```
> <input class="search" type="search" data-column="0" placeholder="Search first column">
> ```
>
> If you want to search all columns, using the updated "any match"
>   method, set the data column value to "all":
>
> ```
> <input class="search" type="search" data-column="all" placeholder="Search entire table">
> ```

What I'd like is to apply my external filter to a collection of columns (more than one, less than all). Ideally, the html could look something like this:

```
<input class="search" type="search" data-column="0,1" placeholder="Search first two columns">
```

or this:

```
<input class="search" type="search" data-column="0" data-column="1" placeholder="Search first two columns">
```

(Is the second one even valid html?)

I've been up and down the tablesorter docs and I haven't had any luck applying the sort that I want. One workaround that I attempted was to present a single input to the user and have it write to hidden inputs which were bound to their respective columns:

```
<input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search first two columns">
// javascript populates the hidden inputs as the user types in the visible one
<input class="search" type="search" data-column="0" style="display: none;">
<input class="search" type="search" data-column="1" style="display: none;">
```

This 'works', except that it now 'AND's the filtering from each individual filter, so that BOTH columns have to match the search term for the row to remain visible rather than EITHER column matching the search term for the row to remain visible. The `data-column="all"` option 'OR's the searches - this is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a great suggestion!

I just added the ability to include multiple columns in an external search input. This change is currently only available within the [working branch of the repository](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/tree/working)

With this change, you can include a range, or multiple columns separated by commas ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4363/)):

```
<input type="search" class="search" data-column="0-1,3,5-7,9">
```

Note:

- This input behaves the same as an input with `data-column="all"` in that "range", "notMatch" and "operators" searches are ignored.
- If multiple inputs exist, the last search will override all previous searches.
- All spaces in the data-column attribute are ignored.

Comment: I noticed after the fact that the current maintainer of the project was active here - was hoping you'd come across the post. Thanks much for the response, and your work with the library. It has saved me a bunch of time (the present corner that I backed myself into notwithstanding). FYI, I also submitted a bug ticket on github having to do with the external filter improperly handling UPPERCASE search terms. I'm currently dodging that issue via the hidden input technique above.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :) I'm not seeing the ticket you mentioned here, do you have the `filter_ignoreCase` option set to `true`?

Comment: https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter/issues/40 is the issue I had opened. It looks like I submitted it to the previous maintainer? Not really familiar with github. The ticket gives a better description of the error than is possible right here. Thanks again.

Comment: Please close that issue and reopen it here: https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter my fork and the original have diverged quite a bit; I plan to rename my fork soon.