# data-column ranges in columnSelector (Mottie's Tablesorter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

It seems that contrary to the behavior described here [Tablesorter: filtering by multiple, but not all, columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470602/tablesorter-filtering-by-multiple-but-not-all-columns) , data-column ranges can't be applied in columnSelector.

For example, using $( "input[data-column='0']" ).attr("data-column", "0-5"); will indeed modify the data-column attribute of the first selector to 0-5 but it will continue to hide only the first column. Use case:

```
|-------------------------------|------------------------------|
|        Super header 1         |        Super header 2        |
|---------------|---------------|--------------|---------------|
| First header  | Second header | Third header | Fourth header |
|---------------|---------------|--------------|---------------|
|    Content    |    Content    |   Content    |   Content     |
|    Content    |    Content    |   Content    |   Content     |
|---------------|---------------|--------------|---------------|
```

In this example, the content is retrieved by Ajax and I'm trying to hide any of the super headers with a columnSelector that displays only them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column selector widget is completely separate from the filter widget, so that comparison won't work in this case. I could make some code changes to accept a range of columns, but then you would need to always build a custom popup in order to use it.

I think what you desire is the [`refreshColumnSelector` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-column-selector.html#methods) which can be used to hide specific columns. Use it as follows:

```
$('table').trigger('refreshColumnSelector', [ [0,1,2,3,4,5] ]);
```

Sorry, it does not accept a range string.